# How to scan using Canon MF3010 in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, scanner, xsane

Recently I bought a Canon MF3010 All in one printer. I got the printing to work after installing the drivers from Canon's website and adding it in CUPS.

How ever I am unable to make use of the scanner.

I tried SANE

Output of sane-find-scanner :

```
   # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9, product=0x2759) at libusb:002:012
found USB scanner (vendor=0x19d2, product=0x2003) at libusb:002:008
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

It seems to identify it but when I run `scanimage -L` i get:

```
device `v4l:/dev/video0' is a Noname CNF9055 virtual device
```

which is my webcam.

My `lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b1d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0930:0214 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 04a9:2759 Canon, Inc.
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Just noticed that this question is still open.  Did you ever get it solved, was it overtaken by events, or do you still need a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install a driver for the scanner.  What Canon offers on its web site is labelled as a printer driver but it isn't clear whether it contains a scanner driver as well, since that is a function of that printer: http://www.usa.canon.com/nw3s/CanonUSA/DownloadContents/English/0100344001EN.htm

If that doesn't include a scanner driver, here is a third party link offering a driver (I'm not familiar with it so I can't comment on it): http://www.driverlook.com/canon-imageclass-mf3010-laser-multifunction-printer-driver-windows-linux-mac-osx/

If the scanner is not recognized after you install the driver, reboot.  If it still is not recognized, verify that you are a member of the scanner group.

Comment: Scanner driver is included in https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/mf3010/imageclass-mf3010?subtab=downloads-drivers I then used `Simple Scan` to scan it.